# How to replace the largest value in each row of numpy array by the average of that row in python?

Tags: python

I have code as shown below. I wanted to find the largest of each row in a numpy array and replace it with the average of that particular row. I have done the part of getting the largest value of each row of the array and replace it with a '1', but cannot replace it with the average of that row. Could anyone help me out in this ?

```
data = [[1,2,3],[2,5,3]]
max_elements = np.amax(data, axis=1)
max_mean = np.mean(data, axis=1)

max_elements = max_elements[:, None]

new_arr = np.where(data == max_elements, 1, data)
print(new_arr)
```

Comment: Try: `new_arr = np.where(data==np.max(data, 1, keepdims=True), np.mean(data, 1, keepdims=True), data)`